# JPanel, панели, фоновый рисунок и другие элементы

Tags: java, swing, gui

Так и не нашёл точного ответа, разобраться самому не выходит. Как разместить на Jpanel ещё несколько панелей и каждой из них задать свой фоновой рисунок так, что бы они не перекрывали элементы и можно было добавлять новые (кнопки, поля и т.д.)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: С менеджерами компоновки у меня нет проблем, это понятно. Добавить фоновый рисунок на панель тоже не проблема. А вот добавить на панель новую панель с рисунком - это проблема